# Present perfect or simple past

Tags: tense, verbs, present-perfect, past-simple

Which of the following is correct?

> 1. It has been two hours since I **have left** LA.
> 2. It has been two hours since I **left** LA.

I know everyone will pick 2 but why one is 1 is not correct as we use present perfect for past events which are relevant to present moment.

Comment: They are both correct. The only reason the second one is more common is because adding *have* is redundant.

Comment: Thanks Sir... Everyone would say 1 is wrong.

Comment: Certainly not *everyone*. And you'd have to define what you mean by *wrong*. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> *It has been two hours since I left LA.*

This is the correct one.
Because your leaving is not relevant to the present time. **You left LA.** The action is finished.

It has been two hours because still you are living in this period of time. Even though after 3 years passed you should use:

> *It has been 3 years since I left LA.*

Answer (score 0):

> It has been two hours since **I have left LA.**
>
> It has been two hours since **I left LA.**

Both are correct. We can use the simple past or the present perfect after **since** depending on the meaning.

I left LA- simple past tense

I have left LA- present perfect tense

The simple past talks about the past. It does not tell us about the present.

The present perfect talks about the past and the present.

**I left LA**. (It refers to a point in the past, a time which is finished)

**I have left LA**. (It refers to a time leading up to the present, a time that continues from the past until now)